# Converting numbers with decimals to text

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to convert numbers to text and this code gives me an error at one of the variables.

Just at the end of the third variable it gives me an "; expected" error.

What's going on in the code?

```
public static string NumberToWords(double doubleNumber)
    {
        var beforeFloatingPoint = (int)Math.Floor(doubleNumber);
        var beforeFloatingPointWord = "{NumberToWords(beforeFloatingPoint)} Rupees";
        var afterFloatingPointWord = "{SmallNumberToWord((int) ((doubleNumber - beforeFloatingPoint) * 100),"")} cents";
        return "{beforeFloatingPointWord} and {afterFloatingPointWord}";
    }
```

the error is exactly at the end of the below line.

```
var afterFloatingPointWord = "{SmallNumberToWord((int) ((doubleNumber - beforeFloatingPoint) * 100),"")} cents";
```

full code is below and now when I run the code I get an error saying input string was not in a correct format (at the button click event). it works without decimal. but with decimal it gives me this error. I'm posting the full code below.

if someone can help me to get this working please.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckPrintingSystem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static string NumberToWords(double doubleNumber)
        {
            var beforeFloatingPoint = (int)Math.Floor(doubleNumber);
            var beforeFloatingPointWord = string.Format("NumberToWords(beforeFloatingPoint)} Rupees");
            var afterFloatingPointWord = string.Format(@"{SmallNumberToWord((int) ((doubleNumber - beforeFloatingPoint) * 100),"")} cents");
            return "{beforeFloatingPointWord} and {afterFloatingPointWord}";
        }

        private static string NumberToWords(int number)
        {


            if (number == 0) return "zero";

            if (number < 0) return "minus" + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

            string words = "";

            if((number / 1000000) > 0)
            {
                words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + "million ";
                number %= 1000000;
            }

            if((number / 1000) > 0)
            {
                words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + "thousand ";
                number %= 1000;
            }

            if ((number / 100) > 0)
            {
                words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + "hundred ";
                number %= 100;
            }

            words = SmallNumberToWord(number,words);
            return words;

        }

        private static string SmallNumberToWord(int number, string words)

        {
            if (number <= 0) return words;
            if (words != "") words += "and ";

                var unitsMap = new[] { "zero ", "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine ", "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ", "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen "};
                var tensMap = new[] { "zero ", "ten ", "twenty ", "thirty ", "fourty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ", "ninety " };
                if (number < 20) words += unitsMap[number];
                else
                {
                    words += tensMap[number / 10];

                    if ((number % 10) > 0) words += " " + unitsMap[number % 10];
                }
                return words;

        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To insert a double quote character in a normal string use a backslash: `\"` (not another double quote). Literal strings (`@"…"`) are different.

Comment: Do you want to use string interpolation? Use $"..." syntax then. Also, notice how you enclose double quotes within double quotes - you have to escape the inner ones.

Comment: Guys I used string.Format and error went away. but I have a new error when I run the code. I have attached the full code above. please help me to get it sorted out. @orhtej2 can't use $syntax it gives me unexpected character error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To correct the error you have to use single quotes for the empty string.

So the code will have to be:

```cs
var afterFloatingPointWord = "{SmallNumberToWord((int) ((doubleNumber
- beforeFloatingPoint) * 100),'')} cents";
```

This is because on the second double quotes the string is expected to be closed.

To make the rest of the code work you'll have to change the code some more.

It will work when you change the NumberToWords method in:

```cs
public static string NumberToWords(double doubleNumber)
{
    var beforeFloatingPoint = (int)Math.Floor(doubleNumber);
    var beforeFloatingPointWord = NumberToWords(beforeFloatingPoint) + " Rupees";
    var afterFloatingPointWord = SmallNumberToWord((int)((doubleNumber - beforeFloatingPoint) * 100), string.Empty) + " cents";
    return beforeFloatingPointWord + " and " + afterFloatingPointWord;
}
```

Comment: I can't use single quote because if use single quote, it gives me two warnings for the second and third variables saying the values have never been used. so I used string.Format and error went away. but I have a new error when I run the code. it's ok when I have only numbers but with decimal I'm getting an error. I have attached the full code above. please help me to get it sorted out.

Comment: I changed the answer with the new NumberToWords implementation. The double has to be converted to an Int to get things working.

Comment: thanks a lot @ Koen Meijer but I get an error on the button click event. private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
        }

Comment: Thanks @Koen Meijer. I got it working. Instead of convert.toint32 I used convert.todouble.